# JScrollPane: Blinker(cursor) is covered by the border

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am working on my own little text editor. Files can be edited in a JScrollPane, now if a line of text is longer than the window, you can scroll to the right as it is ment to be. But when the Blinker(or whatever it's called) is at the very end of the line, it's not visible because it seems to be covered by the border.

```
//the JTextArea is inside the JScrollPane of course
Border scrollPaneBorder = new LineBorder(interfaceColor, 8, true);
Border textAreaBorder = new LineBorder(backgroundColor, 4, true);
```

Setting both borders to 0 won't change anything. Has anyone got a way to deal with this problem?

The most elegant solution in my opinion is the one in Notepad++. There it somehow puts some space between the text and the border as soon as you get close to the border. But I don't know how/if this is possible in java.

Whatever solution, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the notepad++ feature you're talking about. It seems to me that it just has a minimum width when you're re-sizing it.

Comment: well, as soon as you get close to the border, it sets some space in between, but it doesn't move the border of the window, if you mean that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of `setMargin`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setMargin-java.awt.Insets-):

> Sets margin space between the text component's border and its text. The text component's default `Border` object will use this value to create the proper margin. However, if a non-default border is set on the text component, it is that `Border` object's responsibility to create the appropriate margin space (else this property will effectively be ignored).

It’s a bit strange that Swing’s text component will move the cursor up to a location that is covered by the painted `Border` if there is no margin, but it explains why the problem occurs when you set a custom `Border` but not with the default border as the default value for the margin property is non-zero.

You can create a custom border that reads the margin property and implements an unpainted inner region of that size or, if you don’t need support for different values for the margin property, you can just combine your border with an empty border to get a similar effect (of a hardcoded margin space):

```
Border textAreaBorder=BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
  BorderFactory.createLineBorder(backgroundColor, 4, true),
  BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2)
);
```

Comment: Thanx a lot for your Help ;)
I didn't think of EmptyBorder, good idea.